# Adding layer to mercurial directory

Tags: terminal, mercurial

I have a Mercury repo and I need to rename a directory from `/animal/dog/` to `/animal/mammal/dog/`. So I did

```
hg rename /animal/dog/ /animal/mammal/dog/
```

But I get an error that says

> abort: destination /animal/mammal/dog/ is not a directory

How do I make it work?

The above steps is what I've tried.

Comment: Just guessing but maybe you can create the new directory then (mass) rename the files found in the source directory? Mercurial doesn't track directories on their own.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve the problem. It turns out I'm not allowed to use relative paths. Once I changed to absolute path, it worked.

Comment: Do you have this backwards?  `/animal/dog/` IS an absolute path.